# Error in getting the sample name now when loading microarray data from GEOquery

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am trying to load a microarray data from GEO using GEOquery for analysis. When i use the following code it is omitting the row with the samplenames. Instead it uses a data row with expression values as header. Could you please help me to solve this issue?
thanks

```
library(GEOquery)    
gset <- getGEO("GSE1729", GSEMatrix =TRUE)   
if (length(gset) > 1) idx <- grep("GPL96", attr(gset, "names")) else idx <- 1   
gset <- gset[[idx]]   
gset
```

Output:

```
Parsed with column specification:   
  .default = col_double(),  
  **`1007_s_at` = col_character()**
)  

See spec(...) for full column specifications.
|=================================================================================| 100%    4 MB
Warning: 68 parsing failures.  
  row     col           expected    actual         file  
22216 SPOT_ID 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE --Control literal data   
22217 SPOT_ID 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE --Control literal data  
22218 SPOT_ID 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE --Control literal data  
22219 SPOT_ID 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE --Control literal data  
22220 SPOT_ID 1/0/T/F/TRUE/FALSE --Control literal data  
..... ....... .................. ......... ............  
See problems(...) for more details.  

ExpressionSet (storageMode: lockedEnvironment)     
assayData: 22282 features, 43 samples     
  element names: exprs    
protocolData: none   
phenoData  
  **sampleNames: 71 55.4 ... 84.8 (43 total)**  
  varLabels: title geo_accession ... data_row_count (26 total)  
  varMetadata: labelDescription  
featureData  
  featureNames: 1053_at 117_at ... AFFX-TrpnX-M_at (22282 total)  
  fvarLabels: ID GB_ACC ... Gene Ontology Molecular Function (16 total)  
  fvarMetadata: Column Description labelDescription  
experimentData: use 'experimentData(object)'  
  pubMedIds: 15674361   
Annotation: GPL96   


> sessionInfo()  
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)  
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)  
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)  

Matrix products: default  

locale:  
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252     
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                            
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252      

attached base packages:  
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base       

other attached packages:  
[1] GEOquery_2.56.0     Biobase_2.48.0      BiocGenerics_0.34.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5       tidyr_1.1.1      crayon_1.3.4     dplyr_1.0.1      R6_2.4.1            
 [6] lifecycle_0.2.0  magrittr_1.5     pillar_1.4.6     rlang_0.4.7      curl_4.3             
[11] rstudioapi_0.11  limma_3.44.3     xml2_1.3.2       vctrs_0.3.2      generics_0.0.2      
[16] ellipsis_0.3.1   tools_4.0.2      readr_1.3.1      glue_1.4.1       purrr_0.3.4         
[21] hms_0.5.3        compiler_4.0.2   pkgconfig_2.0.3  tidyselect_1.1.0 tibble_3.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems line 8 in that file (ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/series/GSE11nnn/GSE11121/matrix/GSE11121_series_matrix.txt.gz) is messed up / contains a control character in the (quoted) second column, which affects proper parsing:

```sh
!Series_title   "Gene expression profile of acute myeloid leukemia"
!Series_geo_accession   "GSE1729"
!Series_status  "Public on Jan 26 2005"
!Series_submission_date "Sep 06 2004"
!Series_last_update_date        "Aug 10 2018"
!Series_pubmed_id       "15674361"
!Series_summary "Gene expression profile of acute myeloid leukemia."
!Series_summary "^M"
...
```

If you download and decompress the file (e.g. using 7-zip on Windows), open it with an editor, delete the tab and save it again, you can read it in with correct sampleNames from the local, modified copy (no need to re-compress).

```r
gset <- getGEO(filename="GSE1729_series_matrix.txt", GSEMatrix =TRUE, parseCharacteristics=TRUE)

## check:
sampleNames(gset)
```